# Prove that the initial and final point of a curve are boundary point for the corresponding manifold

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, solution-verification, manifolds-with-boundary

What shown below is a reference from the text *Analysis on Manifolds* by James Munkres. **If you know the definition of manifold and of manifold boundary you can only read the last lemma in the image**.

[image]

So now let be $\alpha:[a,b]\rightarrow\Bbb R^n$ a $C^r$ function. Well since the interval $[a,b]$ is diffeomorphic to the interval $[0,1]$ without loss of generality we can suppose that $a=0$ and $b=1$. So in this case the map $\alpha|_{[0,1)}$ is a local patch of $M:=\alpha\Big[[0,1]\Big]$ defined in a set that is open in $H^1$ but not in $\Bbb R$ so that the point $\alpha(0)$ is a boudary point. Now let be $\phi:[0,1)\rightarrow(0,1]$ the diffeomorphism given by the equation
$$
\phi(x):=1-x
$$
for any $x\in[0,1)$ so that the map $\alpha\circ\phi:[0,1)\rightarrow M$ is a local patch of $M$ defined in a set that is open in $H^1$ but not in $\Bbb R$ so that the point $\big(\alpha\circ\phi\big)(0)=\alpha\big(\phi(0)\big)=\alpha(1)$ is a boundary point. However if we put
$$
\phi(x):=\frac 1 2-x
$$
then the point $\alpha\Big(\frac 1 2\Big)=\alpha(\frac 1 2-0)=\alpha\big(\phi(0)\big)=\big(\alpha\circ\phi\big)(0)$ was a boundary point too and this very strangerly because the map $\alpha|_{(0,1)}$ is a local patch about $\alpha\Big(\frac 1 2\Big)$ defined in an open set of $\Bbb R$ and the point $c$ of the lemma $24.2$ implies that the point $a$ can not be true as you can see in the proof and in any case the boundary and the interor of a manifold are disjoint directely by its definition. So I am sure there is something wrong in my arguments but I do not see it and so I ask to find it. So is correct the proof I gave to show that $\alpha(1)$ is a boundary point? So could someone help me, please?

Comment: You're not paying attention to domains. How is $\alpha(1/2)$ a boundary point?

Comment: @TedShifrin The problem is that $\alpha(1/2)=\alpha(1/2-0)=\alpha(\phi(0))$ and it seems to me that $\alpha(\phi(0))$ is a boundary point because the map $\alpha\circ\phi$ is defined in a right neigborhood of zero. So what can you say about? Where am I getting wrong?

Comment: By your logic, any point of $\Bbb R$ is a boundary point if you take a chart with the right domain. Just take $\alpha\colon [a,b)\to\Bbb R$, $\alpha(x)=x$, and you're going to tell me that $a$ is a boundary point of $\Bbb R$. Read his definition very carefully.

Comment: @TedShifrin Okay, and clerly this is impossible. But why my arguments are incorrect with respect Munkres formalism? So how prove that $\alpha(b)$ is a boundary point? I am wrong when I use the diffeomorphism $\phi$ to create a local patch about $\alpha(1)$? Could you explain this, please? Forgive my confusion.

Comment: Munkres is very careful to define a boundary point to be a point that is *not* an interior point — not a point that is the image of a boundary point under some chart. (Definitions can be done in different ways, but Munkres is very careful here.)

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes, clearly there are only two possible cases: a chart defined in a open set exist or not, there are not other possibilities. But the problem is that  the map $\alpha\circ\phi|_{[0,1/2)}$ where $$\phi(x):=1/2-x$$ for any $x\in\Bbb R$ would be a local patch about $\alpha(1/2)$ and defined in a right neighborhood of zero so that by  the lemma $24.2$ the poin $\alpha(\phi(0))=\alpha(1/2)$ woud be a boundary point. So what mistake do I make by referring to lemma 24.2?

Comment: A half-closed interval in $\Bbb R$ and an open interval in $\Bbb R$ are *not* homeomorphic.

Comment: @TedShifrin Surely, and where I say this? Excuse me if I do not see this terrible mistake in my arguments.

Comment: It's in Munkres's definition of a coordinate patch. A coordinate patch must first and foremost be a homeomorphism.

Comment: Surely, and the application $\alpha\circ\phi|_{[0,1/2)}$ is not an homoemorphism? Indeed $\phi|_{[0,1/2)}$ is an homeomorphism from $[0,1/2)$ to $(0,1/2]$ and $\alpha$ is an homeomorphism and so is their composition. What is the mistake here?

Comment: You're forgetting about the topology on the actual manifold. Read very carefully the proof of (c) in the lemma. The inverse function theorem tells you that a diffeomorphism cannot map an boundary point to an interior point.

Comment: @TedShifrin Okay I reread it. So using the inverse function theorem Munkres conclude that if $W_1$ was open in $\Bbb R^k$ then $W_0$ would be open too and this is impossible because it is an open set of $H^k$ that is not disjoint from $∂H^k$. This seems clear to me. So where now I have to apply this to show the incorrectness of my arguments? Exuse me, but my brain is stalled: there is any trivial mistake I do not see.

Comment: Anyway what matters now is to know if the argument I used to show that the point α(1) is a boundary point is correct: could you say it to me, please?