# Does identifying countably many points prevent a quotient space from being second countable?

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

There is a well-known counterexample to the claim that quotient spaces of second countable spaces are second countable. It is $\mathbb{R} / \sim$ where
$$
x \sim y \iff x = y \text{ or } x, y \in \mathbb{Z}.
$$

I want to know if there is a generalization to this. Specifically, is it true that any quotient space of an uncountable second countable space within which we identify countably many points will fail to be second countable? Follow up question: is there a nice necessary and sufficient condition for quotient spaces of second countable spaces being second countable? Maybe if the quotient map is open? I know that's sufficient but I don't know if it's necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you an identify $[0,1]$ to a point and the result is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R$ again, and there we even identify uncountably many points. So it has to be decided on  a case by case basis. If $X$ is compact, Hausdorff, second countable and we identify a closed set to a point, then $X{/}\sim$ is again second countable. This even holds for such an $X$ that is non-compact (but $T_2$ and $C_2$) and where we identify a compact set to a point. (In that case the quotient map is perfect). If the quotient map is closed and all classes are compact, we have the same general theorem we can use: that $C_2$ is preserved by perfect maps..

Comment: Hi professor Brandsma, could I ask your assistance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4036897/prove-that-the-initial-and-final-point-of-a-curve-are-boundary-point-for-the-cor?noredirect=1#comment8336413_4036897), please? There is any trivial mistake thatmy brain do not see now.

Comment: Do you think it's possible to construct a condition which will cause this issue in every case? It seems like with the example in the original post, the issue is that the points we identify have "enough space" in-between them, which is to say there's an uncountable neighborhood of each identified point which intersects no other identified point.

Comment: Is the condition I gave above, namely requiring open quotients, in a sense stronger or weaker than the condition you gave? (That $X$ is compact and Hausdorff, and that the identified set is closed.)

Comment: @bxw $\Bbb Z$ is closed unbounded and discrete. That's "the root cause". Open as a condition, is "independent" from the condition I named.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful.